# Usage of apposition for time?

Tags: appositives

I wrote:

> Pre-Assignments are set *immediately after a node is matched*, **before visiting any child node**.

The bold part actually rephrase the preceding phrase (italic part).

Is it a case of apposition?

A similar example is:

> I do my homework immediately after I come home, before doing anything else.

Comment: Where are you getting these sentences from?

Comment: @BillJ I wrote it for my paper.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "The bold part actually rephrase the first clause", nor do I understand the meaning of the sentence, but I am sure that there is no appositive in your sentence.

Comment: @BillJ I clarified it, it can substitute the phrase after *set*.

Comment: Are you asking us to proof-read for you?

Comment: @billj no, I like to learn this type of appositive phrase. I can use either of them to be sure there is nothing wrong, but I like to learn how to construct such appositions.

Comment: There is no appositive in your sentence. "Before visiting any child node" (whatever that means) is an adjunct in clause structure. An appositive is a noun phrase that modifies another noun and can replace the whole NP, as in _I went to see the opera Carmen_, where "Carmen" is an appositive NP modifying "the opera"

Comment: @billj I added another example. What's the related grammar?

Comment: _Immediately after I come home_ and _before doing anything else_ are preposition phrases functioning as temporal adjuncts. They modify the verb phrase _do my homework_, by stating when you do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51890/discussion-between-billj-and-ahmad).

Comment: @billj then my sentence has a valid structure and I can adjoin several prepositional phrases like that. Right?

Comment: We're in Chat now.